# Customise stripe button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Im using stripe checkout in my rails app. I have been following thier tutorial [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails). Its very basic and I have the payment process working.

What I'm having trouble with is styling the button in the following code. This script contains the button (Im not sure if i said that right), but this brings in the default button:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="500"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
```

Iv tried applying styles to the strip-button class but have no luck, I have also looked within the doc provided but cant find nothing within it to suggest how I could style the default button.

Any suggestions or could thier be a better way in styling the button?

Comment: You're styling a script tag? What are you trying to achieve? Is this code generating a button? can you show us the HTML DOM of the generated code?

Comment: the script generates the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a little [code pen](http://codepen.io/Elektron1c97/pen/LkAXOP)

I think you'll have to use this selector in you stylesheet:

```
.stripe-button-el {
  width: 100px;
  # ...
}
```

Here's the DOM part you want to style:

```
<button type="submit" class="stripe-button-el" style="visibility: visible;">
  <span style="display: block; min-height: 30px;">Pay with Card</span>
</button>
```

EDIT:

The DOM part above is injected by the script you include. (You can imagine as it was there all the time). So you have to style this DOM part (in your css).

See my [pen](http://codepen.io/Elektron1c97/pen/LkAXOP) how to change styles.

I think this question is closed now, as you asked how to style it.

Comment: Iv tried using .stripe-button-el, it still doesnot work check the following link, i tried to apply styles to the button http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxyLbg

Comment: where would i place this code that you provided? within the script?

Comment: What? No you're misunderstanding something. See the edit.

Comment: Ok i understand but, im trying to style the button but can only customise width and height, Iv edited you pen to apply styles but they dont work

Comment: Try setting the style on the span: **.sprite-button-el span** selector

Comment: the only thing that gets styled is the width and the height

Comment: Look at this pen:http://codepen.io/Elektron1c97/pen/LkAXOP
The font-size and everything gets styled!

Comment: iv tried changing the colour of the button, that does not work

Comment: You have to set the `background-image: none;` because there is a gradient. see: http://codepen.io/Elektron1c97/pen/LkAXOP

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on [siegy22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630489/2271122) because I don't have enough reputation here, but I've gotten this to work.

```
.stripe-button-el {
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 0.2em !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #0000ff !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

.stripe-button-el span {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    border-radius: 0.2em !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background: #0000ff !important;
    background-color: #0000ff !important;
}
```

What's happening in that [Codepen above](http://codepen.io/Elektron1c97/pen/LkAXOP) is the script in the Stripe form is running *after* the CSS on Codepen runs. This is why the button changes after you edit any of the CSS on Codepen.

I've found to get around this, just add `!important` to the CSS changes you've made. I know this isn't best practice but it overrides the Stripe script in the form, so this works for me.